# Does moment lib support 1st , 2nd, 3rd rather than 1ST, 2ND, 3RD?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does moment lib support 1st , 2nd, 3rd rather than 1ST, 2ND, 3RD?

I use {moment(this.state.date).format("dddd, MMM Do")} and it shows FRIDAY, JULY 1ST rather than FRIDAY, JULY 1st

Comment: `moment().format('dddd, MMM Do')` gives me `"Thursday, Jul 30th"`. Are you doing anything to make it uppercase? Via CSS rules maybe?

Comment: Let me check. By the way, is it possible to let "th" on the right top of  30?  30^th

Comment: Not without methods the library provides I think. `.format` just returns a plain string. If you want it to *look* differently then you would have to turn the string into DOM elements somehow and style those appropriately.